# Show that $1/2<k<1$ if $y$ can get any real value for two distinct real values of $x$.

Tags: inequality, roots, rational-functions

This problem is from a Sri Lankan grade 12 term test paper.

> Let $y=\frac{1-kx}{(x-1)(x-2)}$; $x \not=1,2$. Show that $1/2<k<1$, such that $y$ can get any real value for two distinct real values of $x$.

I solved this one in a way. But, I am still not satisfied with my methods. Anyone please explain what those methods do. I would like to know what are the applications of these problems.

My effort:

I transformed this equation to:
$$yx^2+(k-3y)x+(2y-1)=0$$

Since there are two distict values for $x$, discriminant>0. By simplifying that inequality,
$$y^2+(4-6k)y+k^2>0$$

Since $y^2$ term coefficient>0, last discriminent must be negative. That gives: $(2k-1)(k-1)<0$ which implies the asked solution.

Comment: What does "... for two distinct real values of $x$" mean?

Comment: I also have the same problem. (Ambiguity) I checked the Sinhalese paper. That also have that ambiguity.

Comment: Remember that it's not sufficient for the discriminant to be positive, we also have to ensure that we truly have a quadratic, meaning the coefficient of the $x^2$ term is non-zero. (You did check it subsequently, for the quadratic in $y$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are meant to prove that the function
$$
f(x) = \frac{1 - kx}{(x-1)(x-2)}
$$
is a $2$-to-$1$ function with range all of $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, for any real number $y$, there are precisely $2$ distinct $x$-values such that $f(x) = y$. It turns out that this is **almost true**. Each $y \neq 0$ has $2$ preimages, but $y = 0$ has only the preimage $x = \tfrac1k$.

---

**EDIT:** I made a silly algebra error, actually looking at solutions to $y = \frac{1}{f(x)}$. But this is equivalent to $Y = f(x)$ for $Y = \frac1y$ (since $y \neq 0$ must be assumed), so the analysis that follows **still works!**

Your approach will work. When we solve $Y = f(x)$ for $x$, we obtain
$$
y(1 - kx) = x^2 - 3x + 2 
$$
or
$$
x^2 + (ky - 3)x + (2 - y) = 0, 
$$
where $y = \frac1Y$, as remarked upon above.

As you note, this is a quadratic equation in $x$ with discriminant
$$
\Delta = (ky - 3)^2 - 4(2 - y) = k^2y^2 + (4 - 6k)y + 1.
$$
We would like to show that for any $\frac12 < k < 1$ and any $y \neq 0$, this quantity is positive, which amounts to showing that
$$
(2 - 3k)^2 < k^2, 
$$
i.e. that
$$
(2k - 1)(k - 1) < 0, 
$$
which is equivalent to the hypotheses about $k$.

Comment: I am curious to know how you have got $y(1-kx)=x^2-3x+2$ in the first step.

Comment: *D'ohhh!* I got that equation by doing absolutely nonsensical "aLgEBrA"  :-)

Comment: Interestingly, though, that equation *is* satisfied by $Y = \frac1y$, which also works to solve the problem since determining that $f(x) = y, \; y \neq 0$ has precisely two solutions for $x$ is the same as determining that $\frac1{f(x)} = Y$ has precisely two solutions. *A happy little accident.*